# SQLite3 slow query parsing

Tags: caching, sqlite

I have a long query like this:

```
SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM tambe WHERE (rowid NOT IN (some 60000 rowids));
```

The query can be potentially executed multiple times, so I save its results in a temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache AS SELECT field1, field2, ... FROM tambe WHERE (rowid NOT IN (some 60000 rowids));
```

This way I don't have to select the actual data every time, but it is still quite a bit slower than it could be. I suspect it is the time it takes to parse the query that is slowing it down.

Is there a way to encapsulate the long query in a kind of IF (CASE) statement so that the SQLite parser would completely ignore it?

```
IF cache NOT EXISTS (...) END IF;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting by rowid doesn't appear to use an index. Using an expression like `id NOT IN (some 60000 ids)` almost certainly won't use an index.

I think your best bet is probably going to be doing a select on a candidate key that's indexed. You might get acceptable performance by doing nothing more than that.

Comment: This is from [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid): _The data for each table in SQLite is stored as a B-Tree structure containing an entry for each table row, using the rowid value as the key. This means that retrieving or sorting records by rowid is fast. Searching for a record with a specific rowid, or for all records with rowids within a specified range is around twice as fast as a similar search made by specifying any other PRIMARY KEY or indexed value._

Comment: After some benchmarking I finally decided to create a temporary in-memory signle-column table with rowids. The WHERE clause then becomes **id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM temp_table)**

Comment: @Petr: I based my comment on the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT...`, which I admit is shaky ground. If SQLite uses an index to find rowids, it doesn't seem to reflect that in the output of `EXPLAIN`. Output is hard for me to read, though. Still, the expression `rowid not in (some 60000 rowids)` almost certainly can't use an index.